# Django ORM - .update(…) with an extra(…) and F(…)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to do one sql query to update a lot of models in a Django site. I want to change one char column/field to be based on the id and some text, in MySQL (which this site is), I'd do that with `"UPDATE table SET blah = 'prefix'||id||'suffix'"`.

My first attempt of doing this in Django was:

```
Model.objects.update(blah='prefix'+F('id')+'suffix')
```

But that tries to give MySQL a `+`, not a `||` operator.

My next attempt was to use the `.extra(…)` like so:

```
Model.objects.extra(select={'newvalue':'"prefix"||id||"suffix"'}).update(blah=F('new_value'))
```

But the `F(…)` is unable to see the new field from the select.

Is there anyway to do this without breaking down to raw SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Django's ORM is multi db compilant. It is not shipped with custom db features such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, this might help:

```
blah = '%s %s %s' %(prefix, id, suffix)

Model.object.update(blah=blah)
```

Comment: No, this solution will set the same value for all objects, the TS wanted to set unique values based on object ID. To make this solution work you need a for loop