# updating a field in model according to count "many to many" field

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration

I have a django model called `Friend` that contains a many to many field called `friends` through another model called `FriendshipInfo`. For performance reasons i decided to hold a field that holds the number of friends each person has. So now in the migration scripts i need to update the existing friends in my db. This is how i did it:

```
def forward(...):
    # ... adding the new count field ...
    for person in Friend.objects.all():
        person.friends_count = len(persion.friends.all())
        person.uupdate()
```

I was wondering if there is any way to do this in a much more efficient way (bulk update somehow?)
Tech info:

1. I am using Python 2.7
2. I am using django 1.6
3. For migrations I'm using south

Comment: At least use `person.friends.count()` instead of `len(person.friends.all())`. From django's doc: "A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into Python objects and calling len() on the result (unless you need to load the objects into memory anyway, in which case len() will be faster)."

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to use the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method to grab the count of friends and bulk update your `Friend` objects like:

```
def forward(...):
    # adding the new count field
    Friend.objects.extra(select = {
        'friends_number': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <your_many_to_many_table_name> WHERE <your_many_to_many_table_name>.<your_FriendshipInfo_related_name> = <your_Friend_table_name>.id'
    }).update(friends_count=F('friends_number'))
```

But, [by the look of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581346/django-orm-update-with-an-extra-and-f), it is not possible. However, you can use <s>the [`raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) method</s> [custom SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) with an [update from count query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701422/update-count-column-from-data-in-another-table):

```
from django.db import connection

def forward(...):
    # adding the new count field
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('\
        UPDATE <your_Friend_table_name>\
        SET friends_count = \
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <your_many_to_many_table_name> WHERE <your_many_to_many_table_name>.<your_FriendshipInfo_related_name> = <your_Friend_table_name>.id)')
```

Comment: Thanks - i was wondering if there is a pure "django orm" way of doing this, as in not writing an sql query.

Comment: The kind of solution i would like to achieve is something like this: `Friend.objects.all().update(firends_count=Count(F('friends')))` - when i try to do this, i get an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Count'` - any thoughts?

Comment: Does `Friend.objects.all().annotate(my_friends_count=Count('friends')).update(friends_count=F('my_friends_count'))` work?

Answer (score 0):

the right way it's in the migration file do the data migration (.py)
there you can put the sql query without a problem, the method is migrations.RUNSQL
here it's a example:

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('procesos', '0020_auto_20150703_1656'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("UPDATE procesos_busquedainmueble SET tipo_inmueble_id=(filtros::json->>'tipo_inmueble')::int;"),
```